# Injecting dependencies - Simpler Way?

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, castle-windsor

This is my `Installer` class in `Windstor Castle` DI/IOC.

```
public void Install(IWindsorContainer container, IConfigurationStore store)
    {
        container.Register(Component
           .For<IServiceRequest>()
           .ImplementedBy<ServiceRequest>()
           .LifestyleScoped());

        container.Register(Classes
            .FromAssemblyContaining<Values1Controller>()
            .BasedOn<IHttpController>()
            .LifestyleScoped());

        container.Register(Classes
            .FromAssemblyContaining<Values2Controller>()
            .BasedOn<IHttpController>()
            .LifestyleScoped());

        container.Register(Component
           .For<IServiceRequest1>()
           .ImplementedBy<ServiceRequest1>()
           .LifestyleScoped());

    }
```

What I am looking is a very simple way of declaring something like

`container.Register(Values1Controller, IServiceRequest, ServiceRequest);`

`container.Register(Values2Controller, IAnotherServiceRequest, AnotherServiceRequest);`

Is there any way to inject dependencies like that?

Comment: You can't get exactly what you want, but should be trivial to write extension function (if one does not exist) that does exactly what you have in first sample with signature like `Register<TInterface, TImpl>(this IWindsorContainer container, Assembly assembly)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As some comment stated in your question, this can be *changed* wrapping that fluent interface using an extension method or a façade.

Anyway, fluent interfaces have been designed to be *simpler* and more flexible than method overloads.

Actually I believe it's not worth the effort (*changing how Windsor registers components*).

I would say you should use Windsor *as is* because your code will be predictable and others might understand it better since they'll find how it works making a quick look at official documentation.